# How can I print this div with drag and drop objects?

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter, drag-and-drop

I can print it but the output is wrong. This is my script for print:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printDiv(divName)
{
    var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
</script>
```

And this is for the view:

```
<div class="accordion-body collapse in body" id="printableArea">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <span class="text-left"><h4><b>Course Code-Section: </b><?php echo $class;?></h4></span>
        <span class="text-left"><h4><b>Course Description: </b><?php echo $description;?></h4></span>
        <span class="text-left"><h4><b>School Year-Semester: </b><?php echo $schoolyearsemester;?></h4></span>
        <span class="text-left"><h4><b>Day-Time: </b><?php echo $daytime;?></h4></span>
        <span class="text-left"><h4><b>Room: </b><?php echo $room;?></h4></span>
        <br>
    </div>

    <ul class="draglist" style="width:{{config.width * config.col}}px;" ng-cloak>
        <li ng-repeat="obj in chairs" ng-drop="false" ng-drop-success="onDropComplete($index, $data,$event)" ng-cloak>
            <div ng-drag="false" ng-drag-data="obj" ng-class="obj" ng-cloak>
                <span class="student-name">{{obj.length > 3 ? obj: ''}}</span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="form-actions">
        <h3 class="text-center">Professor's Table</h3>
    </div>

</div>
    <input type="button" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" value="Print Seatplan" />
```

And this is the image or output that displaying:

[image: Print view]

And this is the one that I am printing, a drag and drop seatplan:

[image: Seatplan view]

Comment: Print option will not render your class, so whatever style-sheet you wrote on class will not get reflected during the print of the page.

Comment: What? Sorry I don't understand

Comment: I mean to say, you have design this HTML using css, right? and while you are trying to print this page it will not apply your css to the HTML structure.

Comment: Then how can I do it to print?

Comment: You can write all css style in `@media print {
   …
}` and omit the media type from link tag. For further you can refer the following link: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Comment: I put it all in @media screen but is not working

Comment: Will you try again after cache clear?